# How can I scale a character to fit into a Rect for drawing text?

Tags: android

I have an ArrayList of Rects, and characters that I want to draw into the individual Rects, one character per Rect.

I want to stretch the text to fit into a given Rect, filling the Rect, so I can use canvas.drawText() to draw the text.

I'm thinking I'll need some combination of setTextSize() and setTextScaleX(), but I don't know where to start for setting the parameters. How can I get my characters to fit into the Rects?

Hopefully someone has solved this problem before and can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this with an [approach](http://catchthecows.com/2011/04/20/Resize_Text_to_Fit_the_View_in_Android/) that uses [`getTextBounds`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect)) to determine the size and scale of text to use:

```java
// Adjust text size to fill rect
paint.setTextSize(100);
paint.setTextScaleX(1.0f);
// ask the paint for the bounding rect if it were to draw this text
Rect bounds = new Rect();
paint.getTextBounds(words[i], 0, words[i].length(), bounds);
// get the height that would have been produced
int h = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;
// figure out what textSize setting would create that height of text
float size  = (((float)(rect.height())/h)*100f);
// and set it into the paint
paint.setTextSize(size);
// Now set the scale.
// do calculation with scale of 1.0 (no scale)
paint.setTextScaleX(1.0f);
// ask the paint for the bounding rect if it were to draw this text.
paint.getTextBounds(words[i], 0, words[i].length(), bounds);
// determine the width
int w = bounds.right - bounds.left;
// calculate the baseline to use so that the entire text is visible including the descenders
int text_h = bounds.bottom-bounds.top;
int baseline =bounds.bottom+((rect.height()-text_h)/2);
// determine how much to scale the width to fit the view
float xscale = ((float) (rect.width())) / w;
// set the scale for the text paint
paint.setTextScaleX(xscale);
canvas.drawText(words[i], frame.left + rect.left * scaleX, frame.top + rect.bottom * scaleY - baseline, paint);
```